# Calculating profit from trading stocks in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have task in shell, we can also use awk.
We got file with records about trading. It looks like this:

```
2021-07-29 23:43:13;TSM;buy;667.90;USD;306;65fb53f6-7943-11eb-80cb-8c85906a186d
2021-07-29 23:43:15;BTC;sell;50100;USD;5;65467d26-7943-11eb-80cb-8c85906a186d
```

We want to know the profit from trades. Third column tells, whether the stock was bought or sold. Fourth column is price per stock, sixth is number of stocks. I tried this, profit should be 46 122.6 USD, but instead, the output is 0. I am new in awk, so I probably messed up syntax.

```
a=$(awk -F ';' 'BEGIN{
    loss=0
    profit=0
    if ($3 == "buy"){
        $loss=($loss + $4*$6)
    } else {
        $profit=(expr $profit + $4*$6)
    }
    {print(profit - loss)}
    }' $FILE)
echo "stonks: $a"
```

Comment: Have a read through [the awk info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) -- the BEGIN block is processed _before_ awk starts to read the file. Therefore, you don't have any of $3/$4/$6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk -F ';' 'BEGIN{x=0} $3=="buy"{x=x-$4*$6}; $3=="sell"{x=x+$4*$6} END{print x}' file
```

or

```
awk -F ';' 'BEGIN{x=0} $3=="buy"{x-=$4*$6}; $3=="sell"{x+=$4*$6} END{print x}' file
```

Output:

```
46122.6
```

Comment: Or, `awk -F ';' '{x += $4 * $6 * ($3 == "buy" ? -1 : 1) } END {print x}' file`

Comment: You don't need the `BEGIN` section, just do `print x+0` in the `END` to handle the empty input file case

Comment: @EdMorton: Yes, you can write the code more compact in several ways. I tried to keep the code easy to follow.